# What does "Ron's face was set" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Black conjured heavy manacles from thin air; soon Pettigrew was upright again, left arm chained to Lupin's right, right arm to Ron's left. **Ron's face was set**. He seemed to have taken Scabbers's true identity as a personal insult. Crookshanks leapt lightly off the bed and led the way out of the room, his bottlebrush tail held jauntily high.

The closest phrase I can get from dictionaries is "**set one's face against**", which means "*To be strongly opposed to or disapproving of something*.", but I'm not sure if it's the intended meaning in this context. What does "*Ron's face was set*" exactly mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When something *sets*, it becomes solid/unchanging. Ron's face has *set* into a single, grim, determined expression.

[to set](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/set_1#set_1__50)

1. if a liquid sets, or if you set it, it forms a solid substance
2. if your face or a part of it sets into a particular expression, or if you set it into a particular expression, you have that expression on your face

[to be set](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/set_3) (adj.)
a set smile or expression does not change, and often hides what someone is really thinking

[the set of somebody’s face/jaw/shoulders etc.](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-set-of-somebody-s-face-jaw-shoulders-etc)
the expression on your face or the way you hold your body, which tells people how you are feeling